# How to disable TLSv1 in Apache 2.4 (Debian 8)?

Tags: debian, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, debian-jessie

I have this line in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf`

`SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2`

However SSL checker `whynopadlock` still shows this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to completely disable TLSv1 in Apache 2.4 (Debian 8) ?

Answer (score 0):

With Apache I always specify them in reverse, i.e. disabling the unwanted protocols. This follows the documentation's examples.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1
```

Comment: Tried it but `whynopadlock` still shows the same warning